# AJAX read javascript file as text file (prevent code repeated)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to read javascript file as text file and prevent code to run multiple time

index.js

```
  version = "1.001";
  alert("JS run");
  ... other code ...
```

and I have html that use index.js 
I try to read index.js by using

```
jQuery.get("js/index.js",function(data){ 
    var currentVersion = data.split("\n")[0].split('"')[1];
}
```

I can read text as I want but alert("JS run") and other code inside also run after I use this code.

Comment: Try setting the `dataType` property.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843132/what-are-the-ways-to-load-javascript-or-css-without-executing-them

Comment: just change data type to "html" and it work fine thank you so much